# how to extract contents from comment to cell in EXCEL VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub CommentToCell()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    Rng.Value = Rng.NoteText
Next
End Sub
```

It is my VBA code. but it makes blank if the cell do not get conmment.

For example, I use this function for in the below cell.

```
1 1 1 0(comments) 1
```

It becomes

```
blank blank blank comments blank
```

I want to get

```
1 1 1 comments 1
```

Comment: I'd check `len(Rng.NoteText)` maybe?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav No.. I don`t want to get length. I want cells without comments to retain their original values.

Comment: Yes, so like i said, i'd check then length is >0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub CommentToCell()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
For Each Rng In WorkRng
If Rng.Comment Is Nothing Then
    Rng.Value = Rng.Value
    Else
    Rng.Value = Rng.NoteText
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

The answer was easier than I thought, and I just had to check the IF statement to see if there was a memo. This works well.

Comment: I would reduce the If to `If Not Rng.Comment Is Nothing Then Rng.Value = Rng.NoteText`

Comment: @FunThomas Good work

Comment: Or possibly use `Rng.CommentThreaded is nothing` depending on the type of comment used (use `Comment` for Notes and `CommentThreaded` for Comments).

Comment: Nice one, Yun!!!